# random order option on java cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber

Does anybody know how to run tests in random order in java cucumber?

In ruby there is the `--order random` option (https://relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber/docs/cli/randomize) but java does not seem to have it according to the command line options printed here https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the up to date options here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/cucumber/api/cli/USAGE.txt

Afaik there is no random option. But you could always ask in the Cucumber Slack (there's a #help-cucumber-jvm channel)